# arm-linux-gnuueabi-gcc cannot find libraries install to custom directory

Tags: c, gcc

I installed two libraries, sphinxbase and pocketsphinx, to /home/phil/sphinx. I'm compiling a test file that uses these two libraries using this line:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc --verbose -o sphinx_test sphinx_test.c \
-DMODELDIR=\"`pkg-config --variable=modeldir pocketsphinx`\" \
`pkg-config --cflags --libs pocketsphinx sphinxbase`
```

However I ultimately get this error with a compile failure:

```
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lpocketsphinx
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lsphinxbase
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.7/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabi/bin/ld: cannot find -lsphinxad
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'd really appreciate any help trying to tell gcc where to like for my library files.

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.4/gcc_3.html#SEC17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message indicates that there's a lack of -L parameter in the expanded gcc command statement.  If you'd like to stick with pkg-config, you need to check the corresponding .pc file to see if the settings are correct.  Otherwise, you might simply add -L/home/phil/sphinx/libs to the gcc command statement to see if the libs work (where /home/phil/sphinx/libs is the .so files located and might be different in your system).

Answer (score 0):

More info: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.4/gcc_3.html#SEC17

You may try something like `-L/home/phil/sphinx -lsphinxbase`